# Convergence of sum of squares relaxations for global polynomial optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, real-algebraic-geometry, sum-of-squares-method

I have studied and understood the Moment-SOS hierarchy proposed by Lasserre where a sequence of semidefinite programs are required to be solved and a rank condition for the moment matrices is invoked in order to check if the global solution is found. I was not able to find such conditions for its dual viewpoint ( also known as the Putinar's Positivstellensatz). Alternatively, is there a similar rank condition for Parrilo's sum-of-squares relaxation?

Comment: This may help: [Minimizing Polynomial Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0103170)